# Function does not read value properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Snapped output of JSON:

```
{"control_mode":0.0,"lvl_danger":0.0,"lvl_alert":0.0,"lvl_normal":0.0,"lvl_upStream":0.0,"lvl_warning"
:0.0,"lvl_downStream":0.0,"lvl_control":null,"rtu_supply":false,"elcb_locked":false,"red_phase":false,
"yellow_phase":false,"blue_phase":false,"gen_status":false,"gen_fail":false,"gen_lowFuel":false,"gen_lowOilPressure"
:false,"gen_lowOverSpeed":false,"gen_highTemp":false,"Gate1":{"gateNo":1,"fullOpen":false,"fullClose"
:false,"opening":false,"closing":false,"mode":0,"state":0,"cond":0,"positionM":0.0,"positionP":0.0}}
```

As you can see, "state":0, in the provided JSON data returned via this url:

```
    var RealDataApi = function () {
    var url_getgatedata = "api/realdata/getgatedata";


    // public functions
    return {
        getGateData: function (done, fail, always) {
            var jqxhr = $.get(url_getgatedata);
            jqXhrHandler(jqxhr, done, fail, always);
        },
```

and then this function to read state and show and hide images based on state value.

```
     RealDataApi.getGateData(
                function (data) {
                    if (data) {

                        $("#pDatetime").html(new Date().toLocaleString());


                        if (data.state == 0)
                        {
                            $("#gate1").show();
                        }
                        else if (data.state == 2)
                        {
                            $("#gate2").show();
                        }
```

So issue here is that the function cannot read state value correctly, and instead of comparing the returned value via url, it always return null?
What is going wrong here?

Comment: `state` seems to be a property of the nested object, so you probably want `data.Gate1.state`. `data.state` doesn't seem to exist. *" instead of compare the returned value from url, it always return null"* What exactly is `null` and where? Please provide a complete example. E.g. it's unclear when/where `RealDataApi.getGateData` is called.

Comment: when `.Gate1.state` is used, this error occurs `TypeError: data.gate1 is undefined
 

if (data.gate1.state == 1)`

Comment: Capital 'G' in 'Gate1', check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`state` is a property of `Gate1`.  You will need to do `data.Gate1.state` (it is case-sensitive so don't forget the capital `G`).

An easy way to check is to use [JSON Linter](http://pro.jsonlint.com/), which will format everything nicely for you.

Simple example:

```
var data = {"control_mode":0.0,"lvl_danger":0.0,"lvl_alert":0.0,"lvl_normal":0.0,"lvl_upStream":0.0,"lvl_warning"
:0.0,"lvl_downStream":0.0,"lvl_control":null,"rtu_supply":false,"elcb_locked":false,"red_phase":false,
"yellow_phase":false,"blue_phase":false,"gen_status":false,"gen_fail":false,"gen_lowFuel":false,"gen_lowOilPressure"
:false,"gen_lowOverSpeed":false,"gen_highTemp":false,"Gate1":{"gateNo":1,"fullOpen":false,"fullClose"
:false,"opening":false,"closing":false,"mode":0,"state":0,"cond":0,"positionM":0.0,"positionP":0.0}}

console.log(data.Gate1.state == 0) // Outputs true
```

Comment: I have tried that but still does not work, still did not read the right value of state

Comment: What does it return? Tyler is right `data.Gate1.state` to access `state`.

Comment: yeah, it works, Tyler is right, because there are many gates so it did not read state from Gate1, but when gate1 is specified, it works. Thanks